# Selecting all records entered in a particular day - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am currently working on a Mailbox for a website, holding a large number of messages within a database, where there is an option to **filter the mails according to the date**. I am in a confusion as of which method to use and how to.

### Method 1:

To use a TIMESTAMP column and select the records based on the DATE part only. This seems to be better considering that the TIMESTAMP is the datatype meant to do this. But when filtering, wouldn't the splitting (to date and time) and comparisons be more expensive. If better, how to perform the comparison? (Input : yyyy-mm-dd)

### Method 2:

To use a column each for TIME and DATE. Then compare the date field value to the filter param (of the format : yyyy-mm-dd). This seems expensive at inserting a new record (mail), which happens only one at a time. But the filtering requires comparison of a large number of records. So, seems to be more straight forward.
Also in method two, I am having a problem setting the default value as the CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_TIME!

This is the Table creation code:

```
CREATE TABLE mailbox (
    Mid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FromId INT NOT NULL,
    ToId INT NOT NULL,
    Subject VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT 'No Subject',
    Message VARCHAR(2048) DEFAULT 'Empty Mail',
    SDate DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    STime TIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (Mid),
    );
```

Please help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use method 1 and do the filtering with

```
WHERE 
     your_timestamp >= search_date 
AND 
     your_timestamp < search_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

assuming your search_date is of type DATE.
MySQL can use an index in this case.

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b19fc/2).
Have a look at the execution plan to verify the use of the index.

Comment: Yes - as long as you specify a range (rather than using a function, such as DATE()), then this will be efficient.

Comment: @Strawberry Updated my fiddle so it shows the use of the index in the execution plan.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I hadn't seen an SQL Fiddle before, and it's brilliant. Thanx for that too. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first that you maintain the records in the table sorted by date. Doing so, allows you to not need to compare every value, but you can use binary search to find the two boundaries (begin and end) of records with the desired date. 
I would also use the time stamp. If you store is as timesstamp and not as text, it will be number, and its very fast at doing the comparison.